# Proportion of data in a sample in R

Tags: r, variables, sample

I have a variable of vehicles:

> vehicleType <- c("suv", "suv", "minivan", "car", "suv", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "car", "suv", "minivan", "car", "minivan", "suv", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "suv", "truck", "truck", "minivan", "suv", "car", "truck", "suv", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "suv", "suv", "minivan", "suv", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "suv", "car", "car", "suv", "minivan", "car", "car", "car", "minivan", "minivan", "minivan", "car", "truck", "car", "car", "car", "suv", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "suv", "car", "suv", "car", "minivan", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car", "car")

How can I calculate the proportion of SUV's in the sample in R?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mean`

```
mean(vehicleType=="suv")
#[1] 0.26
```

Or to find the proportions of all the elements, use `prop.table`

```
prop.table(table(vehicleType))
#   vehicleType
#   car minivan     suv   truck 
#  0.55    0.13    0.26    0.06
```

Answer (score 0):

Use table() function:

```
> table(vehicleType)
vehicleType
    car minivan     suv   truck 
     55      13      26       6
```

For proportion, you may use:

```
> table(vehicleType) / length(vehicleType)
vehicleType
    car minivan     suv   truck 
   0.55    0.13    0.26    0.06
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function table() as:

```
> table(vehicleType)
vehicleType
car minivan     suv   truck 
 55      13      26       6
```

Also to find the proportion, you may devide the table by the size of the data:

```
> summary(table(vehicleType))
Number of cases in table: 100 
Number of factors: 1 
> table(vehicleType) / 100
vehicleType
car minivan     suv   truck 
0.55    0.13    0.26    0.06
```